# Qual é a diferença entre erro sintático e semântico?

Tags: algoritmo, sintaxe

Os conceitos de erro sintático e semântico são encontrados em livros e outros materiais sobre programação. No entanto,  sempre geram dúvidas para quem está iniciando.

De forma prática. Qual a diferença entre erro sintático e semântico?

Comment: Você viu que teve nova resposta postada com bastante atraso? Está satisfeito com sua escolha de aceitação da melhor? Sabe que pode trocar se achar que tem outra melhor depois? Não precisa. Se acha que a que atende melhor é essa mesma pode manter.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Assim como na linguagem natural, nas linguagens de programação se espera que os diversos símbolos sejam dispostos de uma forma lógica uns em relação aos outros, tal como as palavras se juntam para formar expressões, orações, frases. Essa característica é a **sintaxe** da linguagem. Um erro sintático portanto é um caso em que as "frases" do programa (instruções, expressões) estão mal formuladas, aquilo que comumente chamamos de "erro gramatical".

Exemplos:

- Parênteses que abrem mas não fecham;
- Dois números um ao lado do outro sem nenhum operador entre eles;
- Duas instruções sem um ponto-e-vírgula entre elas;
- Uma palavra-chave sendo usada numa posição inesperada.

Há um tipo de erro ainda mais básico, que é quando o símbolo em si está mal formado (ex.: um número com letras no meio - `123y4`), que seria um erro "léxico" ou, como normalmente dizemos, um "erro de ortografia". Esse tipo de erro pode ser agrupado junto dos erros sintáticos, a menos que quisermos ser muito puristas/pedantes.

Já a **semântica** refere-se ao *significado* daquilo que se quer dizer. Da mesma forma que uma frase em linguagem natural possa estar gramaticalmente correta, mas não fazer o menor sentido, também as instruções dadas ao computador podem estar bem formatadas mas não fazer aquilo que o programador quer - ou mesmo nada de útil ou ainda possível.

Exemplos:

- Dividir um número por uma string;
- Criar uma classe que herda de si mesma;
- Usar o operador `^` achando que é de exponenciação, mas na verdade é um ou exclusivo;
- Dividir zero por zero.

Os erros de sintaxe são sempre detectados em tempo de compilação/*parse* (pois se o compilador não consegue sequer montar uma frase, não pode fazer mais nada com ela). Já os semânticos, podem também ser pegos durante a compilação (seja na análise de tipos, na geração de código, ou em outras fases) mas podem também não o ser, e acabarem por provocar um erro em tempo de execução - ou ao menos um resultado/comportamento incorreto. Ou seja, o compilador analisa o código-fonte com sucesso, gera código de máquina, executa, e o problema só se manifesta durante essa execução (sendo ou não imediatamente notado).

Answer (score 25):

<sup>[Sei que esta é uma pergunta antiga, mas não me dou por satisfeito com nenhuma das respostas existentes.]</sup>

Os compiladores da maioria das linguagens de programação são divididos em várias etapas:

- Análise léxica;
- Análise sintática;
- Análise semântica e
- Geração de código.

Dependendo do compilador, pode haver mais do que uma etapa de geração de código ou etapas de otimização junto a geração de código. Algumas linguagens (ex: JavaScript, Ruby, Python, Perl, PHP) praticamente não têm análise semântica. Em algumas linguagens de programação, a análise léxica e a sintática não são separáveis.

Além disso, como bem notado no [comentário do Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105438/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-erro-sint%c3%a1tico-e-sem%c3%a2ntico/245663#comment503545_245663), "*normalmente, o pipeline do compilador não espera a análise léxica concluir-se inteira antes de começar sintática, assim como a saída da análise sintática já pode ser consumido imediatamente pela parte semântica e assim por diante.*"

Assim sendo, um erro léxico é um erro que ocorre na etapa de análise léxica. Um erro sintático é um erro que ocorre na análise sintática. Um erro semântico é um que ocorre na análise semântica. E um erro de lógica é um erro que ocorre em tempo de execução (e não de compilação). Existem também casos onde erros são detectados na geração de código, mas esses são significativamente raros.

Vamos pegar por exemplo, a linguagem Java, que têm todas essas etapas bem separadas e sei é uma linguagem que o autor da pergunta conhece.

## Erro léxico

Um exemplo de programa com alguns erros léxicos seria isso:

```java
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 25 + 0x; #
        "abc
    }
} /*
```

A análise léxica divide o programa em tokens, que é mais ou menos como palavras. Por exemplo, o `public` é um token, o `class` é um token, o `{` é um token, o `;` é um token. A análise léxica também faz uma classificação rápida dos tokens quanto ao seu tipo, de forma que o analisador léxico sabe que `class` é uma palavra chave, que `Teste` é um identificador, que `[` é um símbolo especial e que `25` é um literal inteiro. O analisador léxico também é responsável por ignorar os comentários.

Vê aquele `0x`? Ele é um erro léxico porque o analisador léxico não conseguirá transformá-lo em um literal inteiro válido. Aquele `#` também é um erro léxico porque no caso do `#`, ele corresponde a algo que o analisador léxico não é capaz de identificar o que é. O `"abc` é uma string que não termina, e portanto o analisador léxico não poderá fornecer um token bem-formado sobre ela, outro erro léxico. O comentário no final que começa e não termina também é um erro léxico.

## Erro sintático

A análise sintática é a responsável por reconhecer a estrutura geral do programa. É nessa etapa que o compilador reconhece onde estão as instruções, as expressões, as classes, métodos, funções, parâmetros, procedimentos, etc. Entretanto, essa etapa não é responsável por avaliar se essa estrutura faz sentido (essa é a análise semântica), ela é responsável apenas por reconhecer a estrutura.

Um exemplo de programa com erros sintáticos seria isso:

```java
public class Teste
    public static void main(String[[] args) {
        int a = 10
        int x = * 25;
    }

    public void void metodoA() {}

    public @void metodoB() {}

    public void metodoC( {

    public int metodoD(int interface) {}

    public int metodoE() {
        double x = new for while;
        do { System.out.println("X"); };
    }
} (
```

Aqui temos esses erros:

- Faltou o `{` na declaração da classe.
- No método `main`, há um `[` a mais na declaração dos parâmetros.
- Faltou um ponto-e-vírgula após o `int a = 10`, e sem ele o compilador não consegue saber onde uma instrução termina e a instrução seguinte começa.
- O `*` no `int x = * 25;` faz com que o compilador não consiga montar uma expressão de multiplicação bem formada porque falta o operando da esquerda.
- O tipo de retorno `void void` do `metodoA` vai fazer o compilador se confundir porque quando ele ver o segundo `void`, ele estaria esperando o nome do método.
- O `@` na declaração do `metodoB` também vai fazer o compilador se confundir.
- No método `metodoC`, observe que tem um `(` que não fecha e um `{` que não fecha.
- No método `metodoD`, a palavra `interface` é uma palavra-chave, e não um identificador. O compilador esperava ver um identificador no lugar do nome do parâmetro.
- O `new for while` vai deixar o compilador bem confuso, afinal de contas o `for` e o `while` não deveriam aparecer aí.
- O `do { System.out.println("X"); };` é malformado porque falta o `while` após o `}`.
- Há um `(` sobrando perdido no final.

Com esses erros sintáticos, o compilador não consegue entender qual é a estrutura do código. Ele não será capaz de separar as instruções uma das outras, os métodos uns dos outros, saber onde a classe começa ou onde termina, etc. Se ele não entende a estrutura do código, nem faz sentido tentar avaliar se essa estrutura está correta ou não. No caso do Java e de algumas outras linguagens de programação, a análise semântica nem será iniciada se houverem erros sintáticos.

## Erro semântico

Uma vez que o compilador conhece a estrutura do código, sabe onde estão e quais são as instruções, os parâmetros, as classes, os métodos, as instruções e como elas estão organizadas, aí temos a etapa onde o compilador irá analisar se essa estrutura faz sentido.

Um exemplo de programa com erros semânticos seria isso:

```java
public class Teste extends Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = "abc" * true;
        int m = 5 * (new Teste(4) + x()) - "z";
        int h = 5.6;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}

    private void x() {
        int[] b = new String[] {"Oi"};
        NaoAchei.naoSei();
        g = 4;
        Runnable p = new Runnable();
        Runnable q = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            protected void run() {}
        };
        q.foo();
        Teste.x();
    }

    class String2 extends String {}

    class Carro implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void what() {}
    }

    class Carro2 extends Runnable {}

    void y(int a, int a) {
        int x;
        int m = 25 * x;
    }
}
```

O compilador consegue entender qual é a estrutura/esqueleto desse código. Ele é capaz de ver a classe e saber onde ela começa e onde ela termina, consegue identificar os métodos que tem, consegue separar as instruções uma das outras. Consegue saber onde estão as adições, multiplicações e subtrações. Ou seja, não há erros sintáticos.

Entretanto, embora o programa seja bem-formado estruturalmente, ele ainda é malformado semanticamente. Eis os erros:

- Uma classe não pode herdar de si mesma.
- Existem dois métodos `main` com a mesma assinatura.
- Não dá para se multiplicar uma `String` por um `boolean`.
- Não há construtor de `Teste` que receba `int` como parâmetro.
- Não é possível somar-se alguma coisa com `x()` porque o resultado desse método é `void`.
- Não é possível subtrair-se uma `String` de alguma outra coisa.
- O número `5.6` não pode ser atribuído a um inteiro.
- No método `x`, a variável `b` deveria receber um array de `int`, não um array de `String`.
- Na instrução `NaoAchei.naoSei();`, não há nenhuma classe ou variável chamada `NaoAchei`, logo não dá para se chamar algum método nela.
- Na instrução `g = 4;`, a variável `g` não foi declarada em lugar nenhum, logo não dá para se saber onde esse valor deveria ser armazenado.
- Na atribuição da variável `p`, ocorre uma tentativa de instanciar-se uma interface.
- Na variável `q`, o método `run()` de `Runnable` é público, mas tenta-se sobrescrevê-lo como protegido. Não se pode enfraquecer-se o nível de acesso.
- Na instrução `q.foo();` temos que `q` é do tipo `Runnable`. Mas `Runnable` não tem nenhum método chamado `foo`.
- Na instrução `Teste.x();`, ocorre que o método `x()` não é estático, logo não pode ser invocado dessa forma sem uma instância.
- A classe `String` é `final`, logo não dá para a classe `String2` herdar dela.
- A classe `Carro` implementa `Runnable` mas não sobreescreve o método `run()` especificado na interface. Essa classe também não é abstrata.
- A classe `Carro` sobreescreve o método `what()`. Mas nenhuma de suas superclasses ou interfaces têm esse método para ser sobreescrito.
- A classe `Carro2` está tentando herdar de uma interface (com `extends`) ao invés de implementá-la (com `implements`).
- O método `y` tem dois parâmetros com o mesmo nome.
- Na instrução `int m = 25 * x;` do método `y`, a variável `x` não foi inicializada.

Com esses erros, embora o compilador consiga entender qual é a estrutura do código, ele não é capaz de entender o que essa estrutura está tentando fazer, ou percebe que não há como criar-se algo válido com tal estrutura, ou percebe que ela está violando regras da linguagem, ou percebe que o código é mal-formado ainda que ele tenha uma estrutura bem-formada.

## Erro de lógica

Mesmo que o compilador não detecte erros no programa e o compile, isso não significa que o mesmo está correto. Podemos ainda ter erros de lógica (bugs) que se manifestam apenas durante a execução do programa. Por exemplo:

```java
public class Teste {
    // Calcula todos os números primos de 0 a 100.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = null;
        System.out.println(x.trim());
    }
}
```

Esse daí vai dar um `NullPointerException` na execução. Observe que o código é sintaticamente bem-formado. Na análise semântica, o compilador consegue ver que a variável `x` recebe um valor válido para o tipo `String`. Ele também vê que o método `trim()` existe no tipo `String`. Ele vê que a classe `System` existe, que tem um campo chamado `out`, que é estático e é público e que o tipo desse campo (`java.io.PrintStream`) oferece o método `println` invocado. Entretanto, isso não significa que o programa vai ser executado sem que ocorra nenhum problema e nem que o que o programa faz é o que o programador queria que fizesse (observe o comentário).

## Erros semânticos vs erros de lógica

Em geral, a ideia da análise semântica é capturar erros semânticos no código. Ou seja, identificar erros de lógica e coisas que seriam impossíveis de dar certo durante a execução. Entretanto, há muitos tipos de problemas que não tem como o compilador verificar (o compilador não tem como saber se o código corresponde ao que o programador queria), e portanto é impossível que a análise semântica seja completa. Apesar disso, uma análise semântica mesmo que parcial ou incompleta pode identificar vários tipos de erros. De fato, o [problema da parada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_parada) é um problema de computação clássico que evidencia que uma análise semântica completa é impossível/indecidível/insolucionável.

Daria para se dizer que erros de lógica são erros semânticos, vez que a finalidade da análise semântica é a de identificar-se coisas que seriam erros de lógica no dado programa, e portanto por esse raciocínio, erro semântico seria um sinônimo para erro de lógica. Porém, frequentemente é útil separar-se os erros que o compilador identifica depois de concluída a análise sintática dos erros que só se manifestam em tempo de execução. Logo, muitas vezes denomina-se como erro semântico os erros de compilação que o compilador produz após ser concluída a análise sintática, enquanto que os erros de lógica seriam aqueles que se manifestam durante a execução e que não foram capturados pelo compilador.

Linguagens interpretadas frequentemente têm pouca ou nenhuma análise semântica. É o caso do JavaScript, do PHP, do Perl, do Python e do Ruby por exemplo. Quando você vai executar um trecho de código nessas linguagens, ele fará internamente uma compilação para realizar a análise sintática e sendo essa bem-sucedida, irá gerar alguma estrutura de dados interna representando o programa (geração de código) e já iniciará a execução do mesmo. O fato de não haver uma etapa de análise semântica, significa que essas linguagens serão bem mais flexíveis em relação a quais programas elas aceitam executar e em relação a o programador pode fazer, mas oferecerão bem menos garantias ao programador em certificar-se que o programa dado é bem-formado. Com isso, muitos erros que poderiam ter sido detectados em tempo de compilação, irão se manifestar apenas em tempo de execução. Por outro lado, vez que a análise semântica não tem como ser completa, é inevitável de que muitos erros de lógica não sejam capturados na análise semântica.

## Erros sintáticos vs erros semânticos

A análise léxica ocorre como parte da análise sintática, e portanto é frequente que os erros léxicos também sejam classificados como um tipo especial de erro sintático. Além disso, a ocorrência de um erro léxico frequentemente impede o compilador ou interpretador de entender a estrutura do programa.

Finalmente, erros sintáticos são erros estruturais no programa que impedem o compilador ou interpretador de entender a estrutura do programa. Erros semânticos são erros que se manifestam em programas estruturalmente bem-formados. Quanto a considerar como erros semânticos apenas aqueles que o compilador captura depois da análise sintática ou como qualquer erro que aconteça depois, mesmo que durante a execução, fica a seu critério.

## Outros tipos de erros

Por fim, ainda há alguns tipos de erros que não se enquadram em nenhuma dessas categorias. Seriam os erros de geração de código (por exemplo, o compilador não conseguiu gerar o executável porque acabou o espaço em disco ou porque o código a ser compilado é grande demais) e problemas e bugs do compilador (quando o compilador entra em loop infinito, ou quando ocorre um erro interno no compilador, ou quando não há memória suficiente para executar o compilador).

Também há os casos onde o programa faz o que o programador espera que faça, mas o usuário o usa de maneira inadequada e acaba produzindo resultados que não são o que ele quer ou do jeito que ele gostaria que fosse. Nesse caso, já se entra em conceitos como usabilidade, definição de requisitos e mudança de requisitos. E diga-se de passagem, problemas nesta área são muito comuns.

Outro caso é se o programa faz o que o programador e o usuário querem que faça, mas ele interage com um outro programa ou serviço e esse outro programa ou serviço se comporta de maneira inesperada, o que seria então um problema de integração. Aqui também dá para colocar os casos onde o programa não interage bem com um sistema operacional ou um hardware que seja muito antigo ou muito novo, ou numa configuração que não foi bem testada, etc.

Comment: Só um detalhe para o leitor curioso que chegar até esse ponto: normalmente, o _pipeline_ do compilador não espera a análise léxica concluir-se inteira antes de começar sintática, assim como a saída da análise sintática já pode ser consumido imediatamente pela parte semântica e assim por diante.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim, de fato.

Comment: Victor, creio que `"abc" * true` seja erro sintático (no Java, pelo menos), pois a operação de multiplicação aceita números e identificadores; `String a = "abc"; boolean marmota = true; int m = a * marmota;` creio que seja o erro semântico que você estava atrás. Outro erro semântico é `int x; int m = 25 * x;`, operação com variável não inicializada

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado `"abc" * true` é erro semântico: https://ideone.com/DKtXYV

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Editei a resposta para incorporar as suas sugestões. Obrigado.

Comment: ok, você está certo :) É que quando escrevi os compiladores para Java (para estudos, claro, nada profissional) eu transformava isso em análise sintática porque eu podia =]

Answer (score 14):

Um erro sintático é quando algum elemento daquela instrução está fora do lugar, seja a falta de um terminador de linha, um operador em um lugar não esperado etc.

Erros semânticos podem acontecer do ponto de vista da máquina(menor chance) e do programador(maior chance).

Erros semânticos ancontecem na maquina quando ela não tem informação suficiente para processar uma instrução(inferir o resultado) mesmo ela sintaticamente correta, um exemplo comum é no SQL ao fazer join entre tabelas quem possuem campos com mesmos nomes.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos INNER JOIN vendas ON id = id // esse id é vendas ou produtos?
SELECT * FROM produtos p INNER JOIN vendas v ON p.id = v.id // correto
```

Erro:

```
ambiguous column reference
```

Quem mais comente erros de interpreção é o programador quando trabalha com o um código complicado(ou não) um exemplo é o acesso de índice que não existe em um array, talvez o programador tenha se confundido que são 3 elementos do array que vai de zero a dois e não de um a três

Ex:

```
 for(int i=0; i<=array.length; i++){
     print array[i]; //array[3] não existe, só deve ir até dois.
```

Para máquina a analise sintatica e semântica é **quase** a mesma, por mais ilegível que seja instrução e desde que não contenha nenhum de sintaxe, a máquina irá executar o que foi solicitado.

O Martin Fowler, tem um [frase interessante](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler) sobre isso.

> Qualquer tolo consegue escrever um código que o computador consegue entender. Bons programadores escrevem código que humanos consigam ler.

Answer (score 6):

> Os erros de sintaxe.

O compilador não entende, por exemplo,  multiplicar uma string com um número inteiro em C. O compilador irá detectá-los, porque ele não pode compilá-los.

> Erros semânticos.

O compilador entende, mas não faz o que você, o programador, desejava que fosse feito. Podem estar usando a variável errado, a operação errada ou operações na ordem errada. Não há nenhuma maneira para o compilador detectar esse erro, pois foi o programador que criou uma lógica errada, mas o compilador compilou sem erros.

Comment: Esta resposta está incorreta. Multiplicar uma string por um inteiro em C é um erro semântico. O que você chama de erros semânticos são na verdade erros de lógica.

Answer (score 3):

Encontrei essa imagem que acredito que ilustra bem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fonte:http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~rcmg/cefet-al/algo/aulas/algo_05_linguagem_algoritmica_2_6pp.pdf

Comment: Esta resposta está incorreta. O que aqui é chamado de erro semântico na verdade é erro de lógica. O que aqui é chamado de erro sintático são os erros semânticos. Erro sintático seria colocar um `Se` sem o `então`, ou colocar um parênteses que abre e não fecha em lugar nenhum.