# Questão de concurso: erro de lógica e erro de semântica?

Tags: algoritmo, sintaxe, semântica, lógica

Participei de um concurso e caiu a seguinte questão:

> 33 - Analise o algoritmo e assinale a opção correta referente a este algoritmo.

Algoritmo Calculo_Media:

```
Var N1, N2, MEDIA: Inteiro
Início
  Leia N1, N2
  MEDIA ← (N1 + N2) / 2
  Se MEDIA >= 7 então
     Escreva “Aprovado”
  Senão
     Escreva “Reprovado”
  Fim_se
Fim
```

A) Quando executado o algoritmo será executado sem erros;

B) O algoritmo será executado, mas existe um erro de semântica;

C) Quando executado o algoritmo terá um erro de lógica, mais não há erro de semântica;

D) Quando executado o algoritmo terá um erro de lógica e um erro de semântica

Marquei a letra "B", pois penso que o erro que existe nesse algoritmo só pode ser de semântica. O gabarito preliminar apontou a letra "C" como correta, após os recursos alteraram para "D".

Além do erro de semântica existe também erro de lógica nesse algoritmo?

[Fonte](http://promunicipio.com/arquivos/20151220_235413_TAE_TECNOLOGO_AN_DESENV_DE_SISTEMAS_RC_GTI.pdf)

Comment: Esse é o tipo de pergunta que cai em concurso? Eu acharia fácil, mas pelo visto tem coisas nestas questões que eu não consigo ver. EU fico imaginando como é possível apontar um erro de lógica se não tem escrito em lufar algum qual é a lógica a ser seguida, ou seja, não há um problema definido. O erro semântico depende da linguagem de algoritmo. Onde diz qual é a linguagem? Tem que adivinhar? Ou está implícito por alguma outra coisa que não está aparente na questão? Alias, prova de concurso com erro de português, maravilha...

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a diferença entre erro sintático e semântico?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105438/91)

Comment: @rray não sei, isto é suposição. Se a prova foi feita por alguém que não sabe português, imagina se sabe fazer uma questão que faça sentido. Eu entraria com recurso impugnando no mínimo a questão. A pergunta em si tem: A) nenhum erro; B) erro ortográfico; C) erro gramatical; D) ambos

Comment: Não tou vendo erro nenhum aí. Aliás, já prestei alguns concursos, e geralmente quem faz as questões de informática claramente não é da área;

Comment: Mesmo assim tou curioso pra alguém apontar algum erro aí. De repente tem alguma pegadinha MUITO discreta. Agora, se o autor da prova falar que o erro é uma `←` no lugar do `=`, tem que apanhar de chinelo de borracha na cara, pois nada impede de `←` ser o símbolo de atribuição dessa linguagem. Por sinal, bem semântica essa seta para atribuição. Só deve ser chatinha de digitar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Eu marcaria resposta A** e depois entraria com recurso primeiro para tentar aceitar a minha resposta, e se não for possível para impugnar a questão. A não ser, claro, que alguém justificasse oficialmente a resposta de maneira plausível.

Não consigo ver erro de execução aí, é um algoritmo simples e "manjado".

Para dizer que tem um erro de lógica deveria haver uma definição de qual é o problema. Isso não está presente, então não é possível atribuir um erro de lógica em algo que não se sabe o que deve fazer.

Para dizer que há um erro semântico é necessário saber as regras da linguagem de programação, mesmo uma linguagem mais abstrata. Existem diversas linguagens de algoritmo, cada uma com suas próprias regras.

Dentro da linguagem de algoritmo que eu conheço e dentro do que eu espero que este algoritmo faça, não há erro algum.

O que alguém pode alegar é que a média está sendo calculada em cima de um valor inteiro. Mas pra mim está ok fazer isto. Só uma definição de que deve aceitar valores decimais é que faria haver um erro de lógica.

Esse erro de lógica em tese poderia ser consequência de um erro semântico, embora eu duvide, acho que o semântico inviabilizaria a execução antes dele, e o consertando a lógica estaria correta. A semântica poderia obrigar a fazer uma conversão para poder fazer este cálculo, mas como vou saber em algo abstrato assim?

Alguém poderia alegar que está aceitando qualquer valor. Duvido que isso seja uma necessidade de um algoritmo tão simples, mas se for, deveria ter um problema definindo isto.

O algoritmo faz tudo corretamente dentro do que a intuitividade determina, não dá para ir além dela. Se algo está faltando é culpa da pergunta mal feita e ela não pode exigir que a pessoa que lê saiba do que se trata.

Além disto eu executei em um "IDE" que entende esse algoritmo e **executou sem erros aparentes**. Claro que eu tive que fazer adaptações porque nenhum que eu achei usava essa sintaxe da questão.

Provavelmente eu justificaria na prova minha escolha. Não sei o quanto isto poderia ajudar alguma coisa.

Pode ser que a questão foi baseada em alguma apostila que a pessoa deveria estudar previamente. Aí tudo mudo, teria que responder o que a apostila diz, mesmo que seja errado, porque o concurso está querendo determinar quem decorou a apostila.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Aí tudo mudo, teria que responder o que a apostila diz, mesmo que seja errado." É esse o horror do nosso mundo...

Answer (score 5):

Poderia ser um erro semântico caso em algum lugar na questão estivesse especificado que as notas podem ser números racionais, então seria um erro usar "Inteiro". Também poderia ser considerado um erro de lógica permitir "ler" notas > 10 ou < 0. Contudo se o enunciado do exercício é somente este eu marcaria "A) Quando executado o algoritmo será executado sem erros;" e diria que se consideraram outra resposta a correta é porque viajaram legal em alguma interpretação altamente subjetiva, o que é irônico em se tratando de uma pergunta sobre a exatidão de um código.

Comment: É. Não dá erro. Fica parado no cursor de N1.

Comment: Se tivesse um "NDA" seria a melhor resposta. Nota negativa é "regra de negócio", e nao problema de algoritmo. Para não aceitar negativo e nem maior que dez, falta por no enunciado que a faixa é essa. Quem disse que a nota não é de 1 a 14?  Ou de -5 a +5 e a média utópica? kkk...

Comment: Sim, exatamente por isso eu disse na sentença seguinte "se o enunciado é somente este...".

Answer (score 4):

Eu concordo com você. Só há um erro de semântica. Em momento algum da questão são fornecidos os valores de N1 e de N2, logo, a execução do algoritmo fará uma parada para receber o valor de N1 e não haverá erro.

Mas nós sabemos que se a soma de N1 com N2 fosse 0, geraria um erro de divisão por zero. Nós sabemos também que a divisão de N1 e N2 por 2 pode gerar um número não inteiro, diferente da declaração de MEDIA. Mas esse erro não ocorreu porque os valores não foram passados e o cálculo não foi feito.

Essa questão é uma pegadinha e depende muito de cada interpretação. Gostaria que outros colegas se manifestassem.

Comment: Ta errado isso. Leia N1 e N2 supostamente é o input. Onde ta tividindo por zero? `( 0 + 0 ) / 2 = 0`, sem problemas. E qual o problema de calcular com inteiros?

Comment: tem razão, @bacco.

Comment: De qq forma, acho que não haveria erro porque o cursor iria parar para receber o valor e os valores não estão na questão.

Comment: A pergunta é muito ruim. Não a do @Denis, mas de quem elaborou a prova. Não posso falar desse concurso em especial, suponho que seja totalmente regular e transparente... Mas já vi outros com pergunta desse tipo que são só pra regularizar o "sobrinho" que trabalha no local.

Comment: Com certeza. Mas foi bom ouvir outras respostas dos colegas.

Answer (score -1):

**O problema:**

A média não pode ser um número inteiro pois se a soma da n1 e n2 resultar em um número impar, a média não vai ser um número inteiro.

Creio que isso seja um erro de lógica também.

Achei isso no phpbrasil

http://phpbrasil.com/artigo/yAVSjjsFq2vR/os-4-tipos-de-erros-em-programacao

Comment: Se as notas da entidade que vai usar a média não admitirem números não inteiros, usar inteiro no algoritmo é uma solução adequada. Para sua resposta ser verdadeira, só olhando a "regra de negócio" da entidade que usa a média. O enunciado é falho nesse sentido. E mesmo que aceitasse, não dá pra afirmar que "quando executado" ocorrerá erro. Depende da entrada. Uma coisa é o código ter um erro, outra é se em determinada condição o erro aparece.