# Qual o padrão mundialmente aceito nas linguagens de programação?

Tags: característica-linguagem, sintaxe, independente-de-linguagem

Na língua portuguesa no Brasil usamos a ABNT se quisermos elaborar um texto altamente correto e preciso diante as normas, e para se fazer entender diante as palavras usamos a dialética.

No MySQL eu sei que usamos o padrão de conformidade SQL-99/ANSI-99. Mas e nas sintaxes de outras linguagens, existe um padrão de conformidade para o interpretador?

Quando precisamos de uma análise do sistema criado em C#, recorremos ao editor de texto Emacs, que apresenta o padrão de conformidade realçando a sintaxe, o Emacs engloba todas as linguagens estruturadas padrão C.

Mas e nas linguagens como Java, PHP, Python, entre outras?

Qual seria o nome desse padrão e o órgão mantenedor dele?

Aproveitando essas questão irei elaborar uma cartilha para iniciar jovens que nunca tiveram contato com a programação a darem seus primeiros passos nas linguagens.

Comment: O que interpretador tem a ver com o assunto? Quer dizer que uma implementação da linguagem que deva se conformar com uma especificação? De que linguagem estamos falando? O exemplo do SQL é uma linguagem específica, quer saber de outras? o que um editor de texto tem a ver com o assunto? O que o Emacs tem a ver?

Comment: O padrão usado é aquele definido pela linguagem. Normalmente advém de uma gramática formal e de [regras semânticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245663/64969). Claro, isso seria o equivalente ao "português" ao falar de ABNT. A formatação em si seria algo mais voltado à escola estilística do padrão de código. Eu, por exemplo, sou "brackets inline", já tem pessoas que são "brackets in new line"

Comment: citei o exemplo dos EMACS pois por padrão ele mostra que a sintaxe pode não ser muito aceita, em outros editores ou IDEs também acontece o mesmo, não sendo preciso citar todos para a explicação ficar clara.

Comment: No do Java, o órgão mantenedor era a Sun. Mas a Sun nunca deu muita bola para isso e deixou ficar abandonado e ultrapassado. A Oracle é a herdeira disso. Entretanto o pessoal da IBM e da Eclipse acabou criando um padrão paralelo. O Google também criou um padrão paralelo para o android. Veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153540/132). Aconteceu algo semelhante ao que acontece na ABNT: A norma da ABNT foca bem mais em referências, mas é frouxa e incompleta em outras áreas, além de haver muitos dissidentes que adotam padrões diversos ou variantes por inúmeros motivos.

Comment: @ESCtoheaven A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 7):

> Na língua portuguesa no Brasil usamos a ABNT se quisermos elaborar um texto altamente correto e preciso diante as normas, e para se fazer entender diante as palavras usamos a dialética.

De forma extremamente limitada, sim. A ABNT fala sobre estilo de texto específico, não sobre norma do texto em si, para isto deve usar dicionário e gramática.

> No MySQL eu sei que usamos o padrão de conformidade SQL-99/ANSI-99. Mas e nas sintaxes de outras linguagens, existe um padrão de conformidade para o interpretador?

O padrão citado é sobre sintaxe e semântica, não sobre estilo.

> Quando precisamos de uma análise do sistema criado em C#, recorremos ao Editor de Texto EMACs, que apresenta o padrão de conformidade realçando a sintaxe, o EMACS engloba todas as linguagens estruturadas padrão "C".

Por acaso está falando da [ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)? Se for isso é a especificação oficial da linguagem, ainda que faz tempo que ela não seja atualizada. Toda implementação que queira dizer que se conforma com o C# padrão deve fazer tudo o que manda esta específica. Foi ratificada pela ISO também sob número [23270](https://www.iso.org/standard/36768.html).

ECMA é o órgão europeu de normatização, é a ABNT ou ANSI (A de American) da Europa. ISO é o órgão mundial. Só vira ISO aquilo que foi adotado por vários órgãos regionais ou nacionais.

> Mas e nas linguagens como Java, PHP, Python, entre outras? Qual seria o nome desse padrão e o órgão mantenedor dele? Aproveitando essas questão irei elaborar uma cartilha para iniciar jovens que nunca tiveram contato com a programação a darem seus primeiros passos nas linguagens.

Cada linguagem tem a sua especificação formal ou não. Algumas apenas usam a implementação padrão como especificação.

[C](https://www.iso.org/standard/57853.html) e [C++](https://www.iso.org/standard/68564.html) são as linguagens que mais claramente usam de especificação formal adotada como normal mundial.

Java (não achei, sei lá se não foi abandonado) e [JavaScript](https://www.iso.org/standard/55755.html) (*no relation*, o nome nem é esse) fizeram o mesmo. [Ruby tem](https://www.iso.org/standard/59579.html).

Que eu saiba Python e PHP não o fizeram. Python tem uma [referência](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html) que é mais ou menos o que mais se aproxima de uma especificação. PHP tem algo que [chamam de especificação](https://github.com/php/php-langspec), nem vou comentar.

[Divirta-se](https://www.iso.org/ics/35.060/x/).

Se está falando de estilo, [Python tem o seu](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), mas é quase informal. Eu fiz um [apanhado de C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101) para nomes. Cada linguagem, ou mesmo equipe grande tem o seu. Não podemos achar que isto é padrão, muito menos norma.

Note que estes órgãos só aprovam o padrão em seus comitês formatos por interessados nele, quem faz o padrão é algo aberto, pode ser uma pessoa, uma empresa, um grupo formado para este fim. Há um comitê para o C++ e outro para o C, a Microsoft é responsável pelo C#, a Oracle pelo Java, a W3C pelo EcmaScript, e assim vai.

Tem vários termos na pergunta e comentários (e na outra resposta também) que não condizem com a realidade, ou pelo menos não é bem assim. E há muitas premissas erradas, e até se falando de coisas que nem cabem no contexto.

Entenda a diferença entre [Especificação e Implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Na parte do emacs, acho que ele está perguntando de onde vêm as regras de syntax highlighting do editor.

Comment: Pode  ser, e se for, aí precisa saber que regras, porque tem pelo menos dois assuntos aí.

Comment: achei muito legal seu texto @Maniero♦, é exatamente isso que eu queria levantar. No caso o tipo de texto em referência da ABNT é o tipo de texto Acadêmico, tipos de citações à autores, etc, como devem ser as margens, citações, tudo o que precisa para diagramar a página onde será inserido o texto. É uma questão de lógica, se queremos um sistema perfeito devemos usar os recursos disponíveis. Entre eles está o manual que as empresas fabricantes de softwares fornecem, mas infelizmente nem sempre tudo é as mil maravilhas, o abstract nem sempre 'roda' na aplicação.

Comment: Quase isso que o @bfavaretto disse, mas de um modo geral não quero saber como o syntax highlighting trabalha

Answer (score -1):

Olá, as linguagens de programação não seguem um padrão de sintaxe único, cada linguagem tem a sua sintaxe. Quem controla a sintaxe é o compilador da linguagem e quem criou o compilador foi quem definiu o padrão da linguagem, por exemplo o ‎James Gosling foi o criador do Java foi ele quem definiu a sintaxe da linguagem e criou o compilador para transformar o que foi escrito (código fonte) em código de máquina
O criador do python, Guido van Rossum, fez a mesma coisa, porém os comandos das duas linguagens são diferentes em alguns casos.
Porém o que está por trás de qualquer linguagem de programação é a logica, algoritmo. Com esses dois recursos não importa a linguagem que você utilize.

Portanto se você quer iniciar alguém em programação deixe a linguagem por último faça-os aprender primeiro logica e algoritmo e deixe-os escolher em qual linguagem vão querer implementar.

Comment: Os termos podem não ser iguais, mas seguem uma lógica, certo? Por exemplo, quando eu digo padrão ANSI/99 significa que todos os programas cuja linguagem seja o SQL, deverão seguir, necessariamente, este padrão adotado. Não sei se fui claro em minha pergunta, mas separadamente em cada linguagem deva existir um padrão para a escrita das linhas que ser quer que o programa leia e execute, caso contrário nada será passado ao interpretador.

Comment: vou lançar em um blog, para quem tiver interesse!

Comment: entendo o que quer dizer, mas minha pergunta traz um elemento relevante, não citada, mas aparentemente já trás uma dica de resposta, exemplificando: 'JavaScript é case-sensitive e usa o conjunto de caracteres Unicode'. Fracamente tipadas ou dinamicamente tipadas.
digamos que sejam normatizadas pelo IEEEE ou IEC como é nas engenharias.

Comment: Você está a procura de normas, em programação você tem boas praticas de programação quando se escreve o código fonte, no caso de definição se uma linguagem é fortemente tipada ou não quem define é quem cria a linguagem não acredito que haja um órgão que regule isso

Comment: Bom, acho que achei a resposta válida.

Comment: COBOL é uma linguagem de programação de alto nível desenvolvida pela primeira vez pelo comité CODASYL (Conference On Data Systems Languages) em 1960. Desde então, a responsabilidade pela elaboração de novos padrões COBOL foi assumida pelo ANSI (American National Standards Institute).

Comment: Assim como existem manuais que não são seguidos, há os que não seguem as práticas contidas no ANSI. Vou ter que ampliar minhas pesquisas para localizar exatamente o que quero.
Grato a todos!

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padrão_de_projeto_de_software

Comment: História da UML
Era uma vez um sistema UML que tinha origem na compilação das "melhores práticas de engenharia" que provaram ter sucesso na modelagem de sistemas grandes e complexos. [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML]
UML é mantido pela [http://www.uml.org]

Comment: UML não tem nada a ver com sintaxe de linguagem. Cada linguagem tem a  própria especificação que define sua sintaxe e sua semântica. No caso do JS, a especificação fica a cargo de um comitê da ECMA (uma associação internacional de normas técnicas). Mas cada uma é uma. Quem mantém a especificação do C# é a Microsoft, do Java é a Sun, e por aí vai. @ESCtoheaven

Comment: mas a UML tem um conjunto de padrões e  figuras que impõem ao programador ir por determinado caminho, uma cartilha do que se deva fazer.

Comment: certo, @bfavaretto, vou estudar esse comitê ECMA  que citou, grato pelo enobrecimento do conteúdo, já serviria de resposta! Por mim chego aqui satisfeito.