# O que seria padronização e especificação de uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: javascript, design-de-linguagem

Eu não entendi, muito bem o que é uma especificação de uma linguagem de programação e muito menos o que é padronizar uma linguagem de programação, mais precisamente a linguagem de programação JavaScript, então minha severas perguntas são:

O que seria uma especificação de uma linguagem?

O que é padronizar uma linguagem?

Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de padronizar uma linguagem?

Outras linguagens são padronizadas? Se não, por que?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O que seria uma especificação de uma linguagem?

Acho que já está explicado em [Especificação e Implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) e [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101). E para o exemplo de JavaScript: [O que é especificação ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181071/101). Também pode ser útil: [Qual o padrão mundialmente aceito nas linguagens de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/273518/101).

> O que é padronizar uma linguagem?

Acho que os *links* acima já dão uma boa noção, mas pra deixar mais claro é criar uma norma que todos implementadores devem seguir para que seus produtos se conformem com a linguagem. Um grupo de pessoas representando entidades interessadas no assunto se reúnem e determinam o que é a linguagem de maneira formal, cria-se um padrão.

> Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de padronizar uma linguagem?

Se há interesse de muitos implementadores adotarem linguagem é importante que todos estejam fazendo mais ou menos a mesma coisa, claro, cada um do seu jeito, com detalhes internos que só interessam a eles, mas que o resultado final, o que interessa para as pessoas que vão usar, o produto se comporte de um jeito padrão e universal. Se não existir isso as pessoas farão de jeitos diferentes e no fundo a linguagem passa ter dialetos e o esforço se fragmenta.

A desvantagem é tornar algumas coisas rígidas. Algumas decisões não são tomadas porque nem todos estão de acordo e a linguagem fica aquém do que poderia.

> Outras linguagens são padronizadas? Se não, por que?

Algumas linguagens são padronizadas formalmente, embora a maioria deixa de se esforçar quando se tornam padrões de fato.

C# e Java são padronizadas (só para citar exemplos), ou eram em versões antigas, hoje existe uma entidade que cuida dessas linguagens e fazem mais ou menos o que querem com ela, mesmo dando a chance da comunidade se manifestar em menor ou maior grau.

Algumas o fazem formalmente mas dentro de seu próprio âmbito o que dá um peso menor. Em alguns casos dizem que o compilador padrão ou a documentação é a especificação do padrão da linguagem.

As outras linguagens *mainstream* que mantém formalismo oficializado por um órgão mundial são C e C++. Existem [outras menos usadas que adotam isto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Programming_languages_with_an_ISO_standard) (a lista não precisa).

Não à toa que JS, C e C++ são meio que linguagens universais na plataforma web e nativa, talvez por isso precisem de mais formalismo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Valeu! esclareceu tudo.