# Linguagem de máquina é hardware, software, ambos ou nenhum?

Tags: assembly, ciência-da-computação, arquitetura-computadores, design-de-linguagem

Linguagem de máquina é hardware ou software? Ou as duas coisas, ou nenhuma? Como se diz, quero dar "nome aos bois".

O livro *The Elements of Computing Systems* diz (traduções minhas):

> Uma linguagem de máquina é um formalismo combinado para codificar instruções de máquina.

Analisando literalmente, o trecho acima trouxe para mim uma certa ambiguidade que reside na palavra "codificar". Codificar significa basicamente transacionar de um conjunto de valores de entrada para um conjunto de valores de saída. O que está sendo codificado, segundo o trecho, são as instruções de máquina. Elas são a entrada e seus resultados a saída? Ou "codificar" no caso se refere a programar através de instruções de máquina?

Ainda, por ser um formalismo entendo que não se pode dizer que seja sequer software: é somente uma convenção, uma formalização de transformações ou um código (no sentido de conjunto de transições), por exemplo.

Faz sentido dizer que linguagem de máquina é um formalismo concretizado como hardware e portanto multifacetado, dependendo do foco que se deseja ter? Ou estamos falando de duas coisas distintas, o formalismo e a concretização do formalismo? Ela não é hardware então, é apenas concretizada neste?

O livro continua, de uma maneira que me deixou ainda mais confuso:

> Linguagem de máquina é a interface mais profunda no empreendimento computacional - a fina linha onde o hardware encontra o software. Esse é o ponto em que os *designs* abstratos dos seres humanos, conforme manifestado em programas de alto nível, são finalmente reduzidos a operações físicas executadas no silício. Portanto, uma linguagem de máquina pode ser interpretada tanto como um artefato de programação quanto como uma parte integral da plataforma de hardware. De fato, assim como dizemos que a linguagem de máquina é projetada para controlar uma plataforma de hardware em particular, podemos dizer que a plataforma de hardware é projetada para executar instruções escritas em uma linguagem de máquina em particular.

A parte final indica que a linguagem de máquina e a plataforma de hardware são feitas "uma para a outra". O design de ambas portanto é conjunto, não é possível projetar uma linguagem sem atrelar ao projeto do hardware. Porém o trecho dá a entender que linguagem de máquina *"pode ser interpretada tanto como um artefato de programação quanto como uma parte integral da plataforma de hardware"*, o que subentende a dualidade citada anteriormente, ou então alguma dualidade semelhante.

O que está faltando ser compreendido para entender corretamente o texto e eliminar a confusão?

Em particular, eu queria um esclarecimento para entender integralmente o sentido de *"a interface (...), a fina linha onde o software encontra o hardware"*.

Ainda um trecho ilustrativo mas que não me esclareceu muito nesse sentido:

> Uma linguagem de máquina pode ser vista como um formalismo combinado, projetado para manipular uma *memória* utilizando um *processador* e um conjunto de *registradores*.

Comment: "Linguagem" não é software nem hardware, é um conjunto de regras – independentemente de serem ou não determinadas pelo hardware. Já um determinado conjunto de instruções escritas em linguagem de máquina é software, sem dúvida.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Linguagem de máquina" não é nem hardware nem software.

- [O que caracteriza uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101)
- [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101)
- [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101)
- [O que seria padronização e especificação de uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/428704/101)
- [Especificação e Implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101)
- [Em que linguagem o HTTP foi escrito quando implementado na Web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177519/101)
- [O que é assembler?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178804/101)

Codificar é transformar em código (conjunto de instruções) um problema que você tem que resolver.

Você codifica algo em Português. Ou em matemática, ou C ou Assembly, etc.

> Codificar significa basicamente transacionar de um conjunto de valores de entrada para um conjunto de valores de saída

Não sei se compreendi, mas parece esquisito e desconheço isso.

Codificar em programação é transformar um problema em uma representação, geralmente textual, seguindo regras específicas de como escrever, para que esse problema seja resolvido de forma reproduzível dentro do hardware.

Todo código precisa de alguma transformação. Seja compilação, seja montagem, ou até transformação simples de caracteres para números.

A linguagem é o formalismo. A concretização é a implementação. O código transformado é a concretização do algoritmo que foi representado por uma linguagem. A linguagem é só uma abstração, seja de máquina ou falada e escrita por humanos.

Quando eu escrevo a palavra "maçã" estou usando a linguagem para representar algo concreto que demos um nome em uma determinada língua.

[image: Maçã]

Aqui estou usando a linguagem fotográfica para representar o mesmo objeto concreto.

Só o objeto em si é concreto. O objeto não é linguagem.

Os transistores que formam uma instrução é o objeto concreto. Eles não são uma linguagem.

As instruções em si existem no hardware. Elas são uma forma de linguagem? Eu acho que não. O hardware tem algoritmos dentro dele através de transistores.

Aí entramos em um ponto mais complicado do que é linguagem de máquina.

O Assembly que é usado para escrever o código de máquina é claramente uma linguagem e o Assembler é um software.

Mas e se você codificar usando números binários? Isto é uma linguagem de programação. Tem a mesma semântica do Assembly e uma sintaxe completamente diferente. Não é hardware e não é software.

Ele fala em "fina linha onde o hardware encontra o software", que demonstra que não é qualquer dos dois.

> não é possível projetar uma linguagem sem atrelar ao projeto do hardware

Não é possível projetar uma linguagem de máquina sem atrelar ao projeto do hardware.

> pode ser construída tanto como um artefato de programação como uma parte integral da plataforma de hardware

De fato essa frase é esquisita. É tradução? Acho que ela gerou a dúvida. Eu acho que só está errado, na forma descrita. Só o autor poderia resolver a questão.

Os *links* acima dão mais informações para entender o que é uma linguagem de programação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Concordo que o trecho destacado esteja confuso. Onde vejo a linha borrar um pouco mais é no caso das FPGA, que permitem implementar determinada lógica rearranjando diretamente o hardware. Mas lógica e software não são a mesma coisa.

Comment: _"Não sei se compreendi, mas parece esquisito e desconheço isso"_ quis dizer que um código (no sentido amplo) é uma função de transição de um conjunto de valores para outro. Ou estou pensando em cifra? Cifra de César e outras eu sei que é isso. Mas indo nesse sentido certamente se usa a palavra "codificar" uma mensagem, ou cifrá-la, correto? Em todo caso, suponho mesmo (acrescentei depois) que foi usado no sentido de codificar instruções, ou seja, o famoso "programar/codar". Em tempo: bonita a maçã, mas deveria ter usado um [cachimbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images) :)

Comment: A _"fina linha onde o hardware encontra o software"_ é a interface (também citei _a posteriori_), então de fato é um "entre duas faces", o hardware que executa e a instrução codificada em número binário. _"Não é possível projetar uma linguagem de máquina sem atrelar ao projeto do hardware":_ e vice-versa, faltou acrescentar, até se pode projetar a linguagem de máquina separada, mas não vai ter aplicação. E por fim, bem observado que fiz a tradução errada, era _"construed"_, que significa interpretada, explicada, traduzida, e não _"constructed"_. Vou corrigir.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code - _"Código é um sistema de regras para converter informação - como uma letra, palavra, som, imagem ou gesto - em uma outra forma, às vezes encurtada ou secreta, para comunicação em um canal de comunicação ou armazenamento em uma mídia de armazenamento"_. Também "codificar" ou "encodar" para a ação correspondente. _"Decodificar é o processo reverso, convertendo símbolos de código de volta para uma forma que o receptor entenda"._ Conforme cita o Petzold, as regras não estão (ou, creio eu, não costumam estar) embutidas no código em si. Ñ foge tanto do q falei :)

Answer (score 0):

Ao que me parece, podemos chamar de hardware aquilo que, aqui, se chamou de "Linguagem de máquina", porque o conjunto de instruções e regras para utilizá-las (assembly) não é mera abstração, mas entradas elétricas em um certo conjunto de contatos metálicos de uma certa arquitetura, o que produz uma saída esperada, também em contatos metálicos predefinidos.

Diferente dos mnemônicos descritos em documentos de referência das arquiteturas, é impossível alterar o conjunto de instruções após a fabricação do hardware.

Basta imaginar que se um assembler (este, sim, um software), construído para receber comandos e transformá-los em suas instruções equivalentes, por qualquer motivo, desobedecesse as letras que formam um mnemônico descrito nos documentos da arquitetura, isso seria confuso, mas possível.

Assim, o conjunto de instruções (assembly) é hardware e faz parte da fabricação de um processador baseado numa arquitetura. Já um montador (assembler) é o software mais básico possível, com uma relação de 1 para 1 entre os comandos disponibilizados e as instruções de hardware que produz, utilizado para produção de todos os outros softwares, incluindo as linguagens de alto nível.

Por fim, **se** (1) uma linguagem puder ser entendida como uma formalização qualquer de conjuntos de operadores, operandos e suas regras e (2) concordarmos, assim, que o conjunto de mnemônicos, de valores possíveis em uma arquitetura e suas regras de uso formam uma linguagem, **então**, (3) também o conjunto de instruções, os valores que operam e suas regras formam uma linguagem (mesmo que não adequada para humanos) já que ambos são equivalentes neste sentido.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Certamente fiz um _overthinking_ quando perguntei, mas é agradável e útil sedimentar o assunto. Hoje compreendendo melhor eu não diria que a linguagem é hardware, sua implementação sim, e sugiro alterar isso na resposta. Como foi citado, ela é um formalismo. Para programar (instruir) uma máquina precisamos formalizar suas instruções (que também devem, naturalmente, casar com o projeto da mesma). E instrução é o que instrui a máquina, os próprios impulsos elétricos que a comandam, e a rigor o que chamamos de instruções são representações dessas instruções (metonímia).

Comment: Não tenho conhecimento suficiente para avaliar o último parágrafo. A especificação/regras da linguagem e seu espaço de palavras se equivalerem? Diria que só se correspondem. Sobre a ISA ser imutável após construído o hardware, fico na dúvida no caso de microprogramação, mas entendo pouco. Sobre o assembler desobedecer as letras, não entendi se fala em aceitar mnemônicos diferentes do especificado ou produzir saída diferente. Em todo caso a linguagem não se altera, se algo é alterado nela, torna-se outra linguagem. Um assembler da linguagem X que descumpre sua especificação deixa de sê-lo.

Comment: Com isso que falei posso chegar à conclusão que um assembler é um montador de representações de instruções, ou ainda um montador de instruções codificadas. E só aí entraram dois códigos na história, um é o código que converte a representação da instrução na instrução propriamente dita (isto é, os bits em impulsos elétricos) e o outro é a sequência de representações de instruções (o programa, ou, no caso, a sua representação, já que o programa seriam as instruções na memória RAM ou ROM), mas neste último caso me parece que "código" assume uma definição um pouco diferente.