# Status HTTP para usuário já cadastrado

Tags: http, http-status

Qual status devo retornar em minha API caso um usuário tente se cadastrar com um nome de usuário ou e-mail já existente no sistema?

Comment: Tem alguma ideia? Qual você usaria e por que?

Comment: Eu pensei no 409 pois existe um conflito entre as informações do sistema e as que estão sendo enviadas.

Comment: É uma boa escolha. Muitas aplicações também utilizam a 200, indiciando que a requisição foi processada com sucesso e o conflito é indicado pelo corpo da resposta.

Comment: Voto no 409 - Conflict, melhor deixar o HTTP explicar o que acontece, com algum detalhamento do que ocorreu de erro na mensagem do body

Comment: 409 ou 200 com a mensagem de erro no body

Comment: **422 Unprocessable Entity** (erro do cliente) - o servidor entende a solicitação, a sintaxe está correta mas o servidor não pode processar ... eu sou cético quanto a informar que um email já está cadastrado más, a maioria dos grandes serviços fazem exatamente isto e com um status **200**

Comment: @LauroMoraes pessoalmente não concordo com o 422 para este caso (não tenho certeza até aqui), o 422 é usado para algum problema na estrutura do conteudo enviado, não erro propriamente dito, por exemplo um XML enviado pode ter a sintaxe correta, mas não esta "semântico", então 422 cairia bem, se for erro de sintaxe mesmo ai então o código poderia ser o 400 (bad request). Leve em consideração que este código também é voltado ao WebDAV, então se entendi se refere a arquivos e alterações/versões de documentos (mas foi o que entendi, me corrijam se eu tiver me equivocado).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento **409** é usado quando há conflito de versão como descrito na [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) ... um cadastro de usuário não opera sobre alterações e versionamento, a consulta ao banco de dados não tem por objetivo alterar/modificar o registro existente, logo retornar **409** não me parece ser o correto

Comment: @LauroMoraes mas eu não disse que era, eu só falei do 422 mesmo, que se refere ao webdav. Agora falando sobre o 409, eu li o link que enviou e não fala sobre versionamento, *resource* pode ser qualquer coisa do lado do servidor, o 409 pode ser qualquer tipo de conflito e isto deve ser descrito no corpo da resposta, depende muito do que vai trabalhar, o termo "source" ali descrito não se refere a "documentos" mas sim a "algo destinado", aliás a questão de versionamento cai justamente no 422 (lembrando que se refere a webdav) [...]

Comment: [...] Então até o momento 422 me parece que com certeza não serve (webdav ok?!) e 409 de primeira parece "servir" por ser abrangente (*Semantics and Content*) e por esperar que as descrição do conflito esteja no body, mas ainda sim tenho duvidas sobre este... Pra ***reforçar*** @LauroMoraes RFC7231 se refere a *Semantics and Content* e RFC4918 se refere a WebDav (sendo este sim para "versões")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como não há convenção/padrão para o caso de uso aqui apresentado, acredito que qualquer resposta seja **"opinativa"** assim como quase todas as respostas apresentadas aqui na comunidade relativas ao uso de códigos de status para requisições `HTTP` ... deixo aqui meus 2 centavos sobre ela:

---

> **400 Bad Request** (porque não utilizá-lo)

Normalmente utilizado para descrever uma solicitação inválida, indicando que a natureza deste erro é de origem do cliente.

Embora a [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) estenda a definição proposta pela [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.1) para tornar o código de status **400** mais amplo e abrangente há toda e qualquer situação que o servidor possa entender não ser um erro dele mediante a requisição, acredito não ser o caso de uso para a questão aqui apresentada uma vez que estamos assumindo que o cliente não cometeu erro algum ao submeter as informação pretendidas para cadastro.

---

> **200 OK**

Não acredito precisar entrar na definição mas de longe este é o queridinho das aplicações para tratar a questão levantada na pergunta.

Usado por grandes e pequenas aplicação, a exemplo disto cito algumas que provavelmente sejam de conhecimento da maioria dos internautas:

- Gmail - realiza uma requisição `POST` assíncrona ao clicar no botão "próxima" após preencher os dados de cadastro para verificar a disponibilidade do email e retorna um status **200** com um objeto que descreve o resultado obtido.
- Twitter - realiza varias requisições `POST` assíncronas assim que o usuário insere dados nos campos de email ou telefone, retornando um status **200** com um objeto que descreve o resultado obtido.
- StackOverflow - vai "logar" caso o email e senha sejam os mesmos já cadastrados, caso a senha seja diferente ira renderizar uma página para recuperação no método `GET` retornando um status **200**
- Facebook - renderiza uma pagina de recuperação com parâmetros no método `GET` retornando um status **200**

Acredito que o uso do código status **200** seja adequado dependendo da abordagem e particularmente acho que o Facebook o faz da melhor forma.

PS: que fique claro, isso não é "puxa-saquismo" pela plataforma Facebook, eu nem tenho conta nesta rede.

---

> **409 Conflict** (porque não utilizar)

A [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) indica que a solicitação não pôde ser concluída devido a um conflito com o estado atual do recurso de destino.

Como apontado nos comentários da questão o recurso (resource) pode ser qualquer coisa no servidor por exemplo:

- um arquivo manipulável de qualquer formato disponível ou não publicamente
- uma referencia, valor ou estrutura presente apenas (alocado) no espaço de memória da aplicação
- um registro no banco de dados
- etc ...

Essa definição realmente é muito ampla más em sua base é **"implícito"** o entendimento de que **"o recurso existe(a) no servidor de destino"**, não há como haver "um conflito no estado" de um recurso que não exista (posso estar errado aqui mas estou aberto a uma definição qualificada).

O intuito de um sistema de cadastro/registro de novos usuários em uma aplicação não é modificar "um registro que já exista", pelo contrário seu objetivo é criar uma nova referencia.

Normalmente como parte da rotina verifica-se se um determinado índice (normalmente o email) já existe no registro más, **esta verificação não tem por objetivo obter o registro para modificá-lo** e por tanto, não vejo como **"coerente"** retornar um código de status **409**.

Um cenário plausível mas fora do escopo da pergunta seria retornar **409** em uma solicitação de atualização de uma informação previamente registrada como um email por exemplo. Caso um novo email seja igual ao antigo email seria indicado retornar **409** com uma carga útil que indique a razão/motivo do conflito.

---

> **422 Unprocessable Entity** (porque usá-lo)

O código de status **422** foi implementado na [RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) assim como outros (207, 423, 424, 507) para **"estender"** a lista padrão definida na [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10) como afirmado na [seção 11 - Extensões de Código de Status para HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11)

Como citado nos comentários da questão o código **422** esta "relacionado" a
WebDAV (Web-based Distributed Authoring and Versioning) criada pela [RFC 2518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2518) e atualizada na [RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918)

Um servidor WebDAV roda em cima da estrutura de um servidor `HTTP` "comum" e antes da RFC 4918 os códigos de status descritos na RFC 2616 eram utilizados para descrever os erros na requisição más, esta RFC (2616) não tinha códigos semanticamente descritivos para erros comuns as operação rotineiramente encontradas, por isso a necessidade de **"adicionar"** mais códigos de status a RFC 2616

Este código de status descreve que o servidor compreende a solicitação, que não há erro na sintaxe mas não pode processá-la ... esta definição é descrita na [seção 11.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)

Uma observação aqui: esta seção (11.2) **"descreve um erro semântico como um exemplo, não como uma regra para o erro"**

O uso do código de status **422** não está vinculado (não tem obrigatoriedade) de ser usado exclusivamente por um sistema (servidor) WebDAV ou qualquer sistema de versionamento como pode ser visto na declaração da [seção 12 - Uso de códigos de status HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-12)

Deixo aqui em livre tradução a parte substancial desta seção:

> Em geral, muitos códigos de status HTTP podem ser usados ​​em resposta a qualquer solicitação, não apenas nos casos descritos neste documento.

...

Não posso afirmar de maneira cabal por não encontrar uma definição más, códigos de status **"devem/deveriam"** ser tratados de maneira agnóstica ao sistema da aplicação alvo da requisição.

Acredito que o código de status **422** deva ser o mais indicado para responder a questão porque se encaixa nos seguintes pontos:

- não há um erro do usuário explicito na sintaxe da requisição (ou seu conteúdo)
- o objetivo do pedido não é modificar o estado de um recurso existente
- o servidor compreende o que lhe foi enviado mas não pode concluir a operação
- o uso deste código não tem "obrigatoriedade" com WebDAV ou qualquer sistema de versão

---

**Conclusão:**

Dada as características da questão (não há um erro na requisição) evite o uso do código **400**, embora tentador ele é genérico em demasia.

Ir com o código **200** não seria errado mas a abordagem é o que de fato definiria sua relevância em relação aos outros códigos visto as circunstancias da questão.

Evite o código **409** visto que o cadastro não tem por objetivo modificar um registro existente (entende-se aqui o registro como um recurso).

Vá de **422** porque **"não há impeditivo para usá-lo"** e este é semanticamente mais coerente com o processo que ocorre na questão.

---

**Referência:**

Uma lista completa e oficial dos códigos de status do protocolo `HTTP` que leva em consideração todas as revisões descritas por RFC's é mantida pela [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml)

Answer (score 5):

Essa resposta é, ao mesmo tempo, uma oposição e um complemento à [resposta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/394699/status-http-para-usu%C3%A1rio-j%C3%A1-cadastrado#394924). As especificações oficiais do HTTP são sucintas e pouco exemplificadas, dando margem para múltiplas interpretações, vou contribuir com a minha...

### 200 Ok

Não vejo sentido retornar um status de sucesso numa requisição que não foi executada com êxito, apesar de ser uma prática muito comum. Ao meu ver, o corpo deve complementar o status e não o contradizer. Se o status está no *range* 2xx, o corpo não deve conter uma mensagem de erro.

### 409 Conflict

Concordo que não deve ser usado, mas discordo do motivo apresentado. Segundo a especificação, não requer que o recurso já exista, apesar de ser o mais provável uso, pode ser que alguma outra ação possa gerar um conflito, não só alterações. Um exemplo que talvez (precisa de uma avaliação melhor do contexto) possa resultar em um 409 é a adição/exclusão de um arquivo no servidor que já foi adicionado/excluído em uma versão anterior.

### 400 Bad Request e 422 Unprocessable Entity

Discordo, ao meu ver (com base em outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105438) na comunidade), uma chave única ou estrutura equivalente (qualquer campo que não possa ter repetido o mesmo valor) que gere um erro por duplicidade é um erro de sintaxe, então um 400 seria o mais adequado, enquanto o 422, semanticamente incorreto.

### 500 Internal Server Error

É uma opção interessante se quiser informar um problema com o campo sem especificar que o mesmo possui um valor repetido. Se quiser proteger uma informação (como o email ou nome de usuário), não divulgando esse valor direta ou indiretamente, me parece o status ideal. Respondendo alguns comentários, o 400 talvez pudesse ser usado para isso, mas é estranho responder que o "erro é do cliente" (mesmo que seja) num erro não se sabe o motivo exato (na verdade se sabe, porém quer que seja exposto assim).

### Conclusão

Pessoalmente, usaria o código 400 ou 500, mas é importante frisar que não existe certo ou errado, apenas opções mais semânticas do que outras, e, mesmo assim, ainda existe a questão da interpretação, como já dito, essa é a minha, não sendo necessariamente a mais semântica, também estou aberto a críticas.

Comment: +1 Tenho que concordar contigo, a outra resposta puxou bastante a forçar uma certa interpretação, e mesmo que **webdav** não seja a obrigatoriedade do uso do 422, ainda sim se trata de versionamento como ponto principal, ele simplesmente pegou uma unica frase do RFC e se embasou nela, o que me pareceu fugir de muitas coisas, além disso ele afirmou que 409 era especificamente sobre versionamento em seu comentário a pergunta, o que simplesmente não é e acabou formulando uma resposta que parece boa [...]

Comment: [...] mas que realmente puxa bastante a forçar uma interpretação que talvez não seja bem o caso. Eu ia formular uma contra resposta, mas acho que vc já fez bem. Se houver desavenças ai sim irei destrinchar o RFC com calma e apontar com clareza os possíveis exageros da outra resposta (se ele realmente estiver exagerando em alguns pontos, pode ser que não) ... Aliás, o autor da pergunta foi apressado demais em escolher como aceita, acho que ele deveria analisar os pontos também, mas ai é "outros 500"

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento, a resposta dele é boa e possui todas as fontes oficiais, mas discordo em alguns aspectos. Fiz uma edição e também adicionei uma outra opção até agora não comentada, o 500

Comment: O 500, é um caso a parte, creio que ele é muito interessante para casos de problemas que não podemos detectar, ou até mesmo de sintaxe, geralmente falhas de configuração em "terceiros", podendo ser o proprio ambiente que gera as respostas HTTP, mas geralmente se refere a configurações e erros não "tratados", ou seja algum tipo de erro "inesperado". Repetir e-mails ou nome de usuários já me parece algo esperado. Mas é interpretação pessoal minha, só acho que complicaria usar 500 neste caso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como você disse, "ele é muito interessante para casos de problemas que não podemos detectar", a ideia é passar para o usuário um erro que não se sabe o motivo e especificar no corpo que está relacionado ao email, sugerindo usar outro. Assim é impossível saber com certeza se o valor já foi usado ou não, se tal campo deve ser privado, não fornecendo para nenhum usuário, exceto o proprietário da conta, me parece mais adequado, talvez o 400, mas é estranho dizer que "a culpa é do usuário" em um erro que não se sabe o que é ou quer ser exposto assim

Comment: @Costamilam eu gostei de **500**, acho bacana caso não queira retornar a informação de que dado registro já existe. Fiquei confuso quanto a rotina de uma aplicação detectar uma possível duplicata e consequentemente tratar o pedido como um **"erro de sintase"**

Comment: @LauroMoraes se não for um erro de sintaxe, que tipo de erro seria? Entendo que é o que se encaixa melhor, mas como falei e refalei, é questão de interpretação

Comment: Boa resposta. +1, inclusive. :) No entanto, discordo em afirmar que o _status_ 500 _possa_ ser usado nesse caso, já que ele indica que há um **erro relacionado ao servidor**, o que não é o caso, tendo em vista que o erro é do **cliente**. Se eu fosse escolher um status, escolheria o 409, que enfatiza um conflito. Se o objetivo fosse proteger os nomes de usuários, optaria por 400, que indica que o erro foi do cliente.